# FOR loop iteration not working

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I am simply trying to get the output from a FOR loop, where the initialized value `i` is iterated over 3 times.

```
remainder = 0.33F;

for (float i = 0; i < 1.00F; i += remainder)
{
  Debug.Log(i);
}
```

This is giving output, as i = 0, i = 0.33 and i=0.66. Why am I not getting i = 0.99?

Comment: then what is the way of doing it such that I get all the desired values of variable 'i' ?

Comment: I retracted the close vote. In general, floating point inaccuracy will cause loops to fail like this. In this case, where remainder=0.33, that can't be happening I think.

Comment: Minor syntax corrections, but works just fine... https://dotnetfiddle.net/JsU2Yu

Comment: I agree with Shar1er80, I tested it too and it works fine, although fails to print 0.99 if `remainder = 1.0f/3.0f`, because of fp inaccuracy.

Comment: In some cases I would try to avoid comparing floats on a for statement and use integer multiplying everything by 100 and printing them dividing by 100. Of course It would cause issues also.

Comment: `for (int idx = 0; idx < 3; idx++) { float i = remainder * idx / 3.0f; ... }`

Comment: I am using this in Unity3D and it doesn't show 0.99. That's weird.

Comment: @Daqs what type is `remainder`?

Comment: So I just did it in a Console app and it printed 0.99.  So maybe it is Unity3D related.  Apropos of Anonymous's question about type, my remainder type was float.  Is that true for you, Daqs?  It would seem like it would have to be from the literal.

Comment: Can you use a decimal type instead of a float?

Comment: You can use MonoDevelop to debug your Unity script code. So, I recommend you do that. Then you can see for yourself why the loop terminates before displaying the 0.99 value. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, I don't see how anyone here would be able to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: Those of you that reported this code to be working, what compiler/VM did you use?

Comment: Also, I think that this is a perfectly good and well-worded question, at least after the edits, and I see no real reason for downvotes or closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Because float point arithmetic isn't precise, and shouldn't expected to be.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Precise explanation of this particular problem would include details of how floats a stored in memory in the C# VM, and how it's different between Microsoft's compiler and Mono's compiler, and how you could get different results if you built on iOS, before and after IL2CPP.

However, I don't think that you need all this information, and to be honest, I'm too lazy to dig this deep. Just as a general rule of thumb, rely on float point arithmetic to be unreliable and imprecise.